# SwiftUI can't directly called modifier When custom Image modifier?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to custom Image modifier just like Text modifier:

```
    struct FlagImage: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
        }
}
```

The first error is

```
Value of type 'FlagImage.Content' (aka '_ViewModifier_Content<FlagImage>') has no member 'renderingMode'

Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'original'
```

and the second error is

```
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'black'
```

Why Image modifier content can't directly called .renderingMode(.original)?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`ViewModifier` is modifier of View, which is generic view, so its content is also opaque some generic view and you cannot apply specific modifiers to it, like `Image.renderingMode`.

The solution is make functional modifier directly to Image in extension, like

```
extension Image {
    func flagImage() -> some View {
        self
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4